# PHP/MySQL mark multiple checkboxes "checked" or not checked based on returned data

Tags: php, html

Example MySQL query:  Returned are two values (Desert and Grasslands.)  I'd like to match those two values to `checkboxes` as `"checked"`  Others will stay `unchecked`.

My PHP result set:

```
$row[biome];

<?php
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($selectQueryBiomeResult)) {
     echo '<input type="checkbox" name="biomeCheck[]" value="Desert"> Desert';
     echo '<input type="checkbox" name="biomeCheck[]" value="Grasslands"> Grasslands';
     echo '<input type="checkbox" name="biomeCheck[]" value="Deciduous Forest"> Deciduous Forest';
     echo '<input type="checkbox" name="biomeCheck[]" value="Tropical Rainforest"> Tropical Rainforest';
}
?>
```

Comment: Does the query return only two rows?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Giving a sample code-

```
<html>

    <?php
        mysql_connect("host", "username", "pwd") or die("connect error");
        mysql_select_db("db_name");
        $res=mysql_query("write your query here");
        $val_array=array();
        while($row=mysql_fetch_array($res))
        {
            $val_array[]=$row[0];
        }
    ?>

    <body>
        <input type="checkbox" name="biomeCheck[]" value="Desert" <?php if(in_array("Desert", $val_array)) echo "checked"?>> Desert;
        <input type="checkbox" name="biomeCheck[]" value="Grasslands" <?php if(in_array("Grasslands", $val_array)) echo "checked"?>> Grasslands;
        <input type="checkbox" name="biomeCheck[]" value="Deciduous Forest" <?php if(in_array("Deciduous Forest", $val_array)) echo "checked"?>> Deciduous Forest;
        <input type="checkbox" name="biomeCheck[]" value="Tropical Rainforest" <?php if(in_array("Tropical Rainforest", $val_array)) echo "checked"?>> Tropical Rainforest;
    </body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

If your result is array then try like this

Example Array

```
$my_array = array(
    'first' => 'Desert', 
    'second' => 'Grasslands', 
    'third' => 'Deciduous Forest'
);

<input type="checkbox" name="vehicle" value="Desert" <?php if(in_array('Desert', $my_array)) echo( 'checked = "checked"'); ?>/> Desert<br />
```